# algorithm for correctly rounded floating point radix conversion

Tags: algorithms, floating-point

Is there any generic algorithm which implements a floating point radix conversion?

Lets say we have a $p$-digit FP number

$A = \sum_{i=0}^{p-1} A_i \beta^{e-i}$

in radix $\beta$ and with $0 \leq A_i < \beta$.

How do we find the $A'_i$, $e'$ values for the $p'$-digit base $\gamma$ FP number

$A' = \sum_{i=0}^{p'-1} A'_i \gamma^{e'-i}$

closest to $A$?

There is one [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80952/convert-a-decimal-floating-point-number-into-a-binary-floating-point-number) which explicitly asks about radix 2 to radix 10 conversion, but unfortunately the answers seem to be specific for these radix combination. Here I ask about the general case.

Also is an intermediate arbitrary precision FP calculation really necessary? (as in the function `strtod` in David Gay's [dtoa.c](http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c))

Comment: Except $A$ and $A'$, do all other variables taking integer values only?  Are $p'$ and $\gamma$ given?

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case, you may need very high precision intermediate results. If your problem is limited, for example p ≤ 50 and e ≤ 1,000, it will be possible to prove how much precision is needed at most - with $1000 \cdot 10^{50}$ possible values to convert, 200 bits precision are likely enough.

In practice, some values can be calculated with correct rounding by calculating them with a single floating point operation with exact operands. Many other values can be calculated rounded correctly (including proof) with just a bit of extra precision. So you can do the calculation with relatively few extra bits of precision, check if you have a proven correctly rounded result, and do the same calculation with more bits if needed.

Example: 10.00073 = 1,000,073 / 100,000 Is the quotient of two exact numbers and therefore correctly rounded. 1e30 = 1e15 x 1e15 = product of two exact numbers. 1,000,000,000,000,000,123,456,789,012,345 = FMA (1e15,1e15, 123,456,789,012,344) = fused multiply-add of there exact numbers.